# Abstracting over type constructors in Python via type annotations

Tags: python, static-analysis, static-typing, mypy, higher-kinded-types

I want to statically enforce that a method of a class returns a value wrapped in some abstract type, that I know nothing about:

E.g. given the abstract class

```
F = ???    

class ThingF(Generic[F]):
    @abstractmethod
    def action(self) -> F[Foo]:
        ...
```

I want to to be able to statically check that this is invalid:

```
class ThingI(ThingF[List]):
    def action(self) -> Foo:
        ...
```

because `action` does not return `List[Foo]`.

However the above declaration for `ThingF` does not even run, because `Generic` expects its arguments to be type variables and I cannot find a way to make `F` a type variable "with a hole".

Both

```
F = TypeVar('F')
```

and

```
T = TypeVar('T')
F = Generic[T]
```

do not work, because either `TypeVar` is not subscriptable or `Generic[~T]` cannot be used as a type variable.

Basically what I want is a "higher kinded type variable", an abstraction of a type constructor, if you will. I.e. something that says "F can be any type that takes another type to produce a concrete type".

Is there any way to express this with Python's type annotations and have it statically checked with `mypy`?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: if you're this interested in leveraging the type system, why not used a more strongly typed language? It's very cool to see this much interest in HKTs with Python. :-)

Comment: Actually I am just curious and my interest in doing that in Python is rather academic. It's the language I am most familiar with, but after some excourse into FP Scala and Haskell I greatly miss the comfort of a powerful type system. I do understand that this is nothing that most Python developers are very familiar with or even have a desire for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Higher Kinded Types with `dry-python/returns`.
We ship both primitives and a custom `mypy` plugin to make it work.

Here's an example with `Mappable` aka `Functor`:

```py
from typing import Callable, TypeVar

from returns.interfaces.mappable import MappableN
from returns.primitives.hkt import Kinded, KindN, kinded

_FirstType = TypeVar('_FirstType')
_SecondType = TypeVar('_SecondType')
_ThirdType = TypeVar('_ThirdType')
_UpdatedType = TypeVar('_UpdatedType')

_MappableKind = TypeVar('_MappableKind', bound=MappableN)


@kinded
def map_(
    container: KindN[_MappableKind, _FirstType, _SecondType, _ThirdType],
    function: Callable[[_FirstType], _UpdatedType],
) -> KindN[_MappableKind, _UpdatedType, _SecondType, _ThirdType]:
    return container.map(function)
```

It will work for any `Mappable`, [examples](https://github.com/dry-python/returns/blob/0f7d02d0c491a7c65c74e6c0645f12fccc53fe18/typesafety/test_pointfree/test_map.yml):

```py
from returns.maybe import Maybe

def test(arg: float) -> int:
        ...

reveal_type(map_(Maybe.from_value(1.5), test))  # N: Revealed type is 'returns.maybe.Maybe[builtins.int]'
```

And:

```py
from returns.result import Result

def test(arg: float) -> int:
    ...

x: Result[float, str]
reveal_type(map_(x, test))  # N: Revealed type is 'returns.result.Result[builtins.int, builtins.str]'
```

It surely has some limitations, like: it only works with a direct `Kind` subtypes and we need a separate alias of `Kind1`, `Kind2`, `Kind3`, etc. Because at the time `mypy` does not support variadic generics.

Source: https://github.com/dry-python/returns/blob/master/returns/primitives/hkt.py
Plugin: https://github.com/dry-python/returns/blob/master/returns/contrib/mypy/_features/kind.py

Docs: https://returns.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/hkt.html

Announcement post: https://sobolevn.me/2020/10/higher-kinded-types-in-python

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the type system (as described in PEP 484) does not support higher-kinded types -- there's some relevant discussion here: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/548.

It's possible that mypy and other type checking tools will gain support for them at some point in the future, but I wouldn't hold my breath. It would require some pretty complicated implementation work to pull off.

Comment: Thank you for the link to that discussion. I was really hoping there would be a way, though. I expect that with the traction strongly typed FP has recently been gaining, there will be more and more people looking for some way to do this in the future. Maybe that will push that feature request further up on the agenda. For now I'll have to accept this as being impossible, though, I guess. Thanks!